# Puzzle of 26 brothers

Tags: logical-deduction

Of all the 26 brothers, I am the first son.
With me it starts, the biggest one
You know it,
the chance to not know is least
Of all the places in the world
It’s  fav hangout is Middle East

Answer (score 2):

The answer might be

> the letter A
>
>  (yes, Dmitry posted that as well but I find one clue explanation a little meager)

Of all the 26 brothers, I am the first son.

> A is the first letter of the alphabet

With me it starts, the biggest one

> This might be a reference to the 'alpha male', often the biggest animal of a group

You know it,
the chance to not know is least

> This might be a reference to the expression 'to know your ABCs'.

Of all the places in the world
It’s fav hangout is Middle East

> ArAbiA contains a lot of As

Comment: It's also rot13(nzbat gur 'zvqqyr' yrggref bs 'RNFG')...

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> The letter A. It is the first one of 26 brothers.